# Why doesn't my .gitignore file work in gitkraken?

Tags: git, gitignore, gitkraken

When I was testing my repo, I run npm run build, and it generates a ton of files, so suddenly my gitkraken has a lot of unstaged files, and it makes Gitkraken so laggy that I even stuck at opening repo.

I find a way to resolve it, but right now it still has a lot of unstaged files. Here's my .gitignore file and how Gitkraken looks like.

```
node_modules/
client/node_modules
```

[image]

As you can see I even used `**/`, but it didn't work, but when I pushed my file to travisCI, it built without `node_modules`, so I am really confused here.

Comment: You need to commit the `.gitignore` file first.

Comment: It's looks like you tracked those files before and then you added them to git ignore, that will not be enough look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-can-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitign
you need to force git forget those files

Comment: Also, your `.gitignore` file _is_ in your repo root, right?